# Stream pages in Spring JPA with a custom query joining two tables that returns a projection of type Java Record?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have the following projection record:

```java
public record Projection(
    Integer   locationCode,
    String    referenceNumber,
    String    excerpt1,
    String    excerpt2,
    String    excerpt3,
    String    contractNumber,
    LocalDate date,
    String    contractType,
    String    type,
    String    code
) {}
```

The repository looks like this:

```java
interface xRepository {
    @Query("""
        SELECT
            tableA.locationCode,
            tableA.referenceNumber,
            tableA.excerpt1,
            tableA.excerpt2,
            tableA.excerpt3,
            tableA.contractNumber,
            tableA.date,
            tableB.contractType,
            tableB.type,
            tableB.code
        FROM
            Tables$TableA tableA
        JOIN
            Tables$TableB tableB
        ON
                tableA.locationCode   =tableB.locationRef
            AND tableA.referenceNumber=tableB.referenceNo
        WHERE
                tableA.x = 'true'
            AND tableB.y = 'false'
            AND tableB.z IS NOT NULL
    """)
    Stream<Tables.Projection> streamProjection(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Every time I try to run the method I get an error that says something along the lines of:

> No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.x.Tables$Projection]

I copy/pasted the properties from both entities into the projection record except for the `@Column` notations.